# DropdownList ID in a DataList is not getting recognised in ASP.NET C# codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

*I have tried populating the dropdownlist in the code behind but it shows an error  "stateID does not exist in the current context". THe dropdownlist is inside the datalist*

ASPX:

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="dataList" OnItemDataBound="dataList_ItemDataBound"  RepeatDirection="Vertical">
 <ItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="stateID" AutoPostBack="true"  cssclass="form-input" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="cityID" AutoPostBack="true"  cssclass="form-input" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>

CodeBehind:

public void LoadStates()    {
 stateID.DataTextField = "Name";
 stateID.DataValueField = "ID";
}


Error: stateID does not exist in the current context.
```

Comment: Where do you call LoadStates?

Comment: @JeroenHeier At page load. Thanks. I resolved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use Control directly inside the data-list Control
use findcontrol property in dataList_ItemDataBound method at there you can set or get the value of control inside the data-list

Answer (score 0):

You need the last two lines I added in your method:

```
public void LoadStates()    
{
    stateID.DataTextField = "Name";
    stateID.DataValueField = "ID";
    // Here you have to specify how you will get your data.
    // Normally, you should have a method call to method
    // that returns all the States. Inside this method you will make
    // probably a call to a DB table etc.
    stateID.DataSource = ... 
    stateID.DataBind();
}
```